# Can you solve this rebus puzzle 1?

Tags: rebus

.......................................................
[image: Rebus]...............................................

Can you solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Disintegrator = "Dis" in "t(h)e grater"

Answer (score 5):

is it:

> new knowledge is great

from:

> news notH + d is grate

?

Comment: This is a good alternative answer, although 'H + d = ledge' is a bit of a stretch...